# How to add a script to the standard path in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

how can i add a custom function / object to the standard array of recognized functions in PowerShell so that i  can call it from the shell of PowerShell?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the function into your profile script. You can find out where this is by looking into the variable `$profile`. That script will be run automatically on starting Powershell (if you are allowed to run scripts) and functions declared in it will be available in every session.